# SHA1 coded in Java yields different results from identical C# code

Tags: java, c#, encryption, sha1, password-encryption

Here is some Java code that hashes a salted password and prints the first byte to the console. The printed value is 62.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

class AuthTest
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        byte[] result;
        byte[] salt = new byte[] { (byte)0xe3, (byte)0x2c, (byte)0xf8, (byte)0x9e, (byte)0x6f, (byte)0xe4, (byte)0xf8, (byte)0x90 };
        byte[] password = "password".getBytes("UTF-8");

        result = getHash(1105, password, salt);
        System.out.println(result[0]);
    }

    public static byte[] getHash(int iterations, byte[] password, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        UnsupportedEncodingException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        md.reset();
        md.update(salt);
        byte[] result = md.digest(password);
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            md.reset();
            result = md.digest(result);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

The following C# code, which I thought was identical to the above, yields the value 40.

```
void Main()
{
    byte[] salt = new byte[] { (byte)0xe3, (byte)0x2c, (byte)0xf8, (byte)0x9e, (byte)0x6f, (byte)0xe4, (byte)0xf8, (byte)0x90 };
    byte[] password = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("password");

    var result = GetHash(1105, password, salt);
    Console.WriteLine(result[0]);
}

public byte[] GetHash(int iterations, byte[] password, byte[] salt)
{
    var saltedPassword = password.Concat(salt).ToArray();
    using (var sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        var result = sha1.ComputeHash(saltedPassword);

        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
        {
            result = sha1.ComputeHash(result);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Could someone please help me spot the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Java version you have the salt followed by the password. In the C# version this is reversed.

Answer (score 3):

One of the major difference is that in Java, `byte` is `signed` while in C#, `byte` is `unsigned`. The equivalent for Java `byte` in C# is `sbyte`, not `byte`.

If you want to get the same result as Java in C#, use `sbyte` for every `byte` you use in `Java`.

Comment: IIUC, sbyte vs byte should not make any difference with respect to the hashing algorithm, just the Console output. In this case, even the console output should have been the same.